# Use parameters with UIRouter and Components

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularfire

Hello everyone I'm having some problem to use ui router with parameters.

I'm using angularfire and all my datas are in firebase.

```
//This is my router
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
 $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url :'/home',
    template :'<home></home>'
  })
  .state('projects', {
    url:'/projects',
    template:   "<project-list></project-list>"
  })
  .state('projectDetails',{
    url:'/project/:id',
    template : '<project-detail></project-detail>'

  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
})
```

And this is the controller inside the component projectList

```
function ProjectListController($scope, $element, $attrs, $firebaseArray, $stateParams) {
var ctrl = this;


 var projects_ref = firebase.database().ref().child("projects");
 var projects = $firebaseArray(projects_ref);
 });


 ctrl.details = function (project) {

      //$state.go('project-details', {: project.$id});
      console.log(project.$id);
      projectId = project.$id;
      return projectId;


  }
```

How do i make that ":id" to work? What I basically want is to have page where all the projects are listed and once I click one link i need the url to be something like "example.com/project/{projectId}

Do you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change state `projectDetails` to `projects.details`. Also, give it it's own controller e.g.:

```
  .state('projects.details',{
     url:'/project/:id',
     template : '<project-detail></project-detail>'
     controller : 'ProjectDetailsCtrl as projectDetailsCtrl'
  });
```

And in your `ProjectDetailsCtrl`, you will have access to the `$stateParams`. e.g.

```
.controller('ProjectDetailsCtrl',['$stateParams',function ProjectDetailsCtrl($stateParams){
    console.log($stateParams.id);
}])
```

Trigger the navigation to the project via a controller using `$state.go('projects.detail',{id:projectId});` assuming `projectId` is a variable with the project id as value. Or via an element using `ui-sref="projects.detail({id:projectId})` assuming `projectId` is available as data to your view.